# Re-ordering arbitrary an array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, random, collections, hashset

I have a method that accepts as argument an array of integers and I'd  just change arbitrary the order of its values

```
public static int[] _game_number = new int[4];
public static int[] _current_number = new int[4];

public static void GetRandomTwentyFour()
{
    HashSet<int> nums = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        nums.Add(r.Next(0, 4));
    }
    List<int> liste = nums.ToList<int>();
    _current_number = new int[] { _game_number[liste[0]], _game_number[liste[1]], _game_number[liste[2]], _game_number[liste[3]] };
}
```

The problem is that the `nums`'s elements count is not always four.

- So, How can I modify my snippet to accomplish my task?
- Is there another way to do this?

Comment: In your snippet, the method does NOT accept the array argument.
Also, based on your code you are trying to create a hashset that contains just 4 entries; why not just use new HashSet<int>(){0,1,2,3}?

Comment: One problem I can see is you're creating new `Random` inside the loop. It will not do what do you expect.

Comment: BTW don't create random inside loop or else you will all same values.

Comment: The problem is that `HashSet` stores uniqe values. So if get f.e. 4 twice from random generator, `HashSet` will store only one `4`. Use f.e. `List` instead of `HashSet`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal sometimes I get different values

Comment: @pwas yes it is the problem that I need to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reorder them randomly, simply use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with a random thing as the selector.

Usually you can use Random.Next()

```
public static int[] _game_number = new int[4];
public static int[] _current_number = new int[4];
private static Random random = new Random();

public static void GetRandomTwentyFour()
{
    _current_number = _game_number.OrderBy(r => random.Next()).ToArray();
}
```

But a new `Guid` would work here too², and save you a private field :

```
public static int[] _game_number = new int[4];
public static int[] _current_number = new int[4];

public static void GetRandomTwentyFour()
{
    _current_number = _game_number.OrderBy(g => new Guid()).ToArray();
}
```

²*Please note that Guids are not made to be "random", but to be "unique". However, as you're probably not making an extremely official application (banking, online poker, etc.) it's fair to use it IMO. For an application where the randomness is very important, the [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Cryptography namespace would be a better bet.*

Comment: Thanks @Pierre : simple ans perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
public static int[] GetRandomTwentyFour(int[] _game_number)
{
    int len = _game_number.Length;

    int[] _current_number = new int[len];

    List<int> nums = new List<int>();

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int rand = r.Next(0, len);

        if (nums.Contains(rand))
        {
            i = i - 1;
            continue;
        }
        else
            nums.Add(rand);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++)
        _current_number[i] = _game_number[nums[i]];

    return _current_number;
}
```

Here is the proof

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about extension method?

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    private static Lazy<Random> random = new Lazy<Random>(() => new Random());

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetReorderedElements<T>(this T[] input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        }

        var rnd = random.Value;        
        var nums = input.ToList();         
        var repeats = unusedNums.Length;

        while (repeats > 0)
        {
            var index_first = rnd.Next(0, nums.Length);
            var index_second = rnd.Next(0, nums.Length);

            var temp = nums[index_first];
            nums[index_first] = nums[index_second];
            nums[index_second] = temp;

            repeats -= 1;
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection(nums);
    }


    public static T[] GetReorderedElementsAsArray<T>(this T[] input)
    {
        return GetRandomElements(input).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
_current_number = _game_number.GetReorderedElementsAsArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just change the `4` to a variable holding the number of elements.

While you're at it, you can organize things a bit. Have your `GetRandom...` method receive the array, check its size (instead of assuming it's 4) and either shuffling it in place if it's something you want, or returning a new array with the same size.

Comment: All of the arrays I used has 4 as size, so I don't need to check it