# Move Items in List Randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list which contains SelectListItem, I am making dropdownList for it.
This is my list element's

```
1 Declined
2 Bad Phone
3 Medical
4 No Answer
5 Try Again
6 Left Voice mail
7 Skip 
8 Not Valid
9 Warning
10 Unemployed
```

The list is sorting according to their values(I have shown values next to the item)
I have to display elements like this

```
5 Try Again
7 Skip 
6 Left Voice mail
3 Medical
8 Not Valid
1 Declined
2 Bad Phone
4 No Answer
9 Warning
10 Unemployed
```

ie in Random Order, How can I do this Random sorting in List, One thing I can do is to find index of each item and change its index/position,but it will be a hectic.
The List items are fixed and are not dynamic.

Comment: Do you want a different order each time?

Comment: If yes, please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25106237/2160375. There is an extension method for array, very easy to change it to accept `IList`.

Comment: No, I have a sorted List and I want to change orders of each item randomly, the new order will be fixed

Comment: you can just try using jquery...

Comment: Will your second order be the one for every time? Or will it be different after a page refresh?

Comment: "I want to change orders of each item randomly, the new order will be fixed". I don't think my english is perfect, but this sentence IMHO has no sense. Or first or second option :)

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos my second order will be one every time

Comment: @pwas May be sentence has no sense, as I am non english person :)

Comment: @Exception How can I do in Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to randomly sort the order, eg.

```
var lstResult = yourList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
```